# Memory implications for recursively computed properties in iOS core data

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a simple data model in Core Data: An entity called "Employee" has several references:

1. supervisor: A to-one relationship to entity Employee. It points to another employee who is the current employee's supervisor;
2. directReports: A to-many relationship to entity Employee. It points to a set of employees who are supervised by the current employee.

Now I want to calculate the total number of direct/indirect reports for any employee. So I created a category Employee+Statistics

```
- (NSUInteger) totalNumberOfSubordinates {
    NSUInteger numberOfSubordinates= [self.directReports count];
    for (Employee *e in self.directReports) {
        numberOfSubordinates += e.totalNumberOfSubordinates ;
    }
    return numberOfSubordinates;
}
```

Here is the question: Does this approach automatically fire all faults when I try to look up the totalNumberOfSubordinates of the CEO? Assuming the data changes frequently, i.e., new employees join and existing employees quit, is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Does this approach automatically fire all faults when I try to look up the totalNumberOfReports of the CEO?**

Yes.

**Is there a better way?**

Yes, but you will probably have to change your model.
Your current solution has a high probability of O(N) faults being fired (going down the supervisors tree).

One example would be to store the total count as a property on the `Employee` entity (say `totalSubordinates`).

When an employee's `supervisor` is set, update that supervisor count (and he will update his supervisors count in turn).
It should look something like this:

```
//NOT TESTED
- (void) setSupervisor:(Employee*)newSup
{
    if (newSup == self.supervisor) {
        return;
    }
    [self.supervisor changeTotalSubordinatesBy:-self.totalSubordinates];
    [newSup changeTotalSubordinatesBy:self.totalSubordinates];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"supervisor"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:newSup forKey:@"supervisor"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"supervisor"];
}

- (void) changeTotalSubordinatesBy:(NSInteger)amount 
{
    if (amount == 0) {
        return;
    }
    self.totalSubordinates += amount;
    [self.supervisor changeTotalSubordinatesBy:amount];
}

- (void) prepareForDeletion
{
    self.supervisor = nil;
}
```

This way you go up the supervisor tree (assuming there are less supervisors then employees) and you have a very low probability of O(N) faults being fired.

Also, you have changed the access time of the `totalSubordinates` to O(1)[in-memory access], and moved the complexity to the times where you change employees supervisor (insert, move, delete)

another method would be to keep the entire supervisor chain for each `Employee` and issue a single count request (here you will complicate the insertion process, and the "master-supervisor" might have relations to all other subordinates, although you can drop the inverse relationship ...).
In this case the complexity would be O(1)[fetch from disk]

Comment: That answers my question! Thanks a lot!